# Submit button in the html form is displaying the php script instead of sending form data to the db

Tags: php, html, forms

I have this problem with the submit button in the html form where by when I click it instead of sending the form details to the database it displays the php script in a new window,I've tried everything I could still not working,please help
html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>sign up</title>
       
        <link href="sign in.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="signbox">
            <h1>SIGN UP HERE</h1>
           
            <form method="" action="connect.php" method="POST">
                <p>First name:</p>
                <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="enter your first name">
                <p>Email address:</p>
                <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="enter your email address">
                <p>Password:</p>
                <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="enter your password">
                <p>Confirm password:</p>
                <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="confirm your password">
                <input type="submit"  value="sign in">
                <a href="log in.html">already have an account?login here.</a>
            </form>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

PHP code:

```
<?php
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$password2 = $_POST['password2'];

//database connection.
$conn = new mysqli('loacalhost','root','','','first_db');
if($conn->connect_error){
    die('connection failed : '.$conn->connect_error);
}else{
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("insert into users3(firstname, email, password, password2)
    values(?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$firstname, $email, $password, $password2);
    $stmt->execute();
    echo "registration complete...";
    $stmt->close();
    $conn->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: check your submit button might be you used anchor tag instead of submit button

Comment: Please, please, please add your code to your question. It's so much easier to help if we can see what you're doing.

Comment: Please add what you've tried already and some code.

Comment: by "it displays the php script" you mean the plain php code as if you would open the file in an editor? 
you need some kind of a webserver to run php code, like apache or nginx. If you are running this code on a webserver, it might be not configured properly.

Answer (score 0):

In your form tag there are 2 method attributes, should be corrected as;

```
<form action="connect.php" method="POST">
```

And also in the php code, [mysqli](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysqli_connect.asp) connection should be;

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost','root','','first_db');
```

in which the four parameter are;

```
$conn= new mysqli("server name","username","password","database name");
```